# Excel: How to use array in conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following dataset, which changes during the day:

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ivf.png)

On row 3 I successfully use conditional formatting to color cells depending on the value in row 2.

Example of conditional formatting in my sheet: Color cell A3 cell red if:

**=A$2+3<=MAX(B2:M2)**

**My problem is:**

How do I use this MAX function if I want it to only use cells between **B2:M2**, where the cells above them **B1:M1** contain text?

Help is much appreciated!

I tried creating arrays, but using ctrl + enter when using conditional formatting doesn't seem to work

*Edit: from the comment section it appeared to be the following problem:*

I want to be able to conditionally format cells in row 2 based on max values in range `A2:M2`. From this range only the values should be taken into account for the max comparison if the cells in range `A1:M1` contain value and column C should be excluded.

If no values are found in `A1:M1` only take all of range `A2:M2` and only exclude column C.

Comment: can you share examples of where you expect cells to be or not be colored? are they only in row 3? only column A?

Comment: Hi, I have a different conditional formatting for every cell on row 3 which are based on the value in all cells that have data on row 2. So for instance

Conditional formatting in A3:

=A$2+3<=MAX(B2:M2)

and conditional formatting in B3:
=B$2+3<=MAX(C3:M2;A2)

This works fine, but I want it to only use the max function on cells where the cell above it has a text in it.

Example:
If
A2: X 
B2: 13

Then use B2 in Max calculation

If
A2:
B2: 13

Then don't use B2 in max calculation

Comment: You mean `MAX(FILTER(B2:M2,B1:M1<>"",B2:M2))`?

Comment: You are a genius. This filters the data where cells B2:M2 have no text, but I can modify it a bit to filter the data where they have a specific text in them, which is what I wanted. Big thanks!

Comment: Hi @P.b When using the same FILTER formula, but with two arrays: **D2:M2** and **A1:B2** while using **D1:M1** and **A1:B1** as criteria. Do you know if this is possible to do this in one single formula?

Comment: I don't understand the relation. They're of different count of columns.

Comment: @P.b my bad. I wrote the wrong cell numbers. Arrays should be **D2:M2** and **A2:B2** and criteria should be **D1:M1** and **A1:B1** in the same formula.

What I'm essentialy trying to do is using the same filter formula that you created, but skipping **C2** in the array and **C1** in the criteria

Comment: Ah, why not use IF there `IF(COLUMN()=3,0,MAX(FILTER (....`

Comment: Hey @P.b , yeah good idea. Appreciate the help! It doesn't seem to quite work for me right now though since with **IF(COLUMN()=3,0,MAX(FILTER (....** the max function won't execute if the column is C. 

The thing is that I would still like to execute the max function when the column is C, I just dont want column C to be used in the Max calculation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select B3:E12.
2. Select Home, Conditional Formatting, New Rule.
3. In the New Formatting Rule dialog, choose “Use a formula to determine which cells to format.”
4. Type =B3=MAX($B3:$E3) in the dialog box.
5. Click the Format… button.
6. In the Format Cells dialog, click the Fill tab and choose a fill color.
7. Click OK to close the Format Cells dialog.
8. Click OK to close the New Formatting Rule.

Comment: Hi, I only want the MAX formula to use cells in the B row when there is text above the cell in the B row.

So if A4 has no text and B4 has "2" then I do not want to use B4 in the max formula.

But if A4 has "hello" and B4 has "2" then I want to use B4 in the max formula

Answer (score 0):

The following takes the max of values in range `A2:M2` if `A1:M1` contain a value, else it takes the max of the whole range `A2:M2`. In both cases it excludes column C from the max values:

```
=A$2+3<=
 MAX(
     FILTER(A$2:M$2,(A$1:M$1<>"")*
                    (COLUMN(A$1:M$1)<>3),              
            FILTER(A$2:M$2,COLUMN(A$1:M$1)<>3)
     )
```